# React Nested Loops and Keys

Tags: reactjs, loops, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to get a bit of react code to work and am struggling with conditional rendering. The following:

```
      <div id="table_holder" className="table-responsive mx-3">
        <table className="table-sm">
          {Tables.map((tableRows, index) => (
            <thead key={'headeer'+index.toString()}><tr key={index.toString()}>
            {tableRows.map((tableRow, i) => (
              <th key={i.toString()}>
                {i}
              </th>
            ))}
            </tr></thead>
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
      );
```

works but I'd like to conditionally display different table cells depending on the the value of the key 'type' in the object tableRow. And can't seem to manage the right syntax

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first loop is not assigning a unique key to the div. That might be the problem. Try to give key like this.

`<key={index}>`

```
 <table className="table-sm">
          {Tables.map((tableRows, index) => (
            <key={index}>
            {tableRows.map((tableRow, i) => (
              <th key={i+index.toString()}>
                {i}
              </th>
            ))}
            </>
          ))}
        </table>
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is how you can use conditional rendering in react.

```
  var tableRow = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Your React App</h1>
      {tableRow.map((table, index) => {
        if (table % 2) {
          return <div key={index}>{table}</div>;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that bit out although I thought <></> was a React fragment and therefore didn't need a key. Would you know how I would add a condition inside the tableRows.map loop? Thanks for responding

Comment: Sure, Please check the edit in the answer. Its a bad example but if works :D

Comment: That works fine. Thanks. I was trying to use```{ table % 2}```. To be 100% honest I'm not sure on when to use React embedded JS and when to use just JS. But thanks this has really helped